# C# Why are some bitmaps resized after copying using GDI+?

Tags: c#, bitmap, copy, gdi

I have a Bitmap variable and I copy smaller 32x32 png files (loaded as Bitmaps) onto the bitmap. However, some png's are scaled up (always the same ones) and appear as 36x36 for example after copying. Almost as if some png's have another DPI or something? How can I prevent this?

```
   Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(destinationImage);
   g.DrawImage(sourceImage, location); // sourceImage is sometimes larger than it actually is. On disk it is 32x32 but after copying it might be bigger...
   g.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are right about DPI, as it's stated in the documentation:

> This method draws an image using its physical size...

I'm too lazy to make a test project, but I think Graphics.DrawImage(Image, Rectangle) with rectangle size equals to source image size will fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Image.Horizontal/VerticalResolution property matters.  If it doesn't match the dots-per-inch setting of your monitor then the image is going to be drawn proportionally larger or smaller.  This tends to be undesirable, use the DragImage(Image, Rectangle) overload to force it to display at exact 32 x 32 pixels.